# Insert multiple rows in mysql with two columns values same and the other column has multiple values

Tags: mysql

I have to update my 'messages' table.

Columns in my table **id, sender, receiver, msgbody**.

Now i want to send messages to multiple receivers at once with a message **Welcome**.

for example:

sender with id=1 will send to receiver id's 2,3,4,5 and i want to insert unique row for each msg.

pls help me with this. thank you.

Comment: That's what you want. First question is: *What have you tried*?

Comment: i tried using INSERT INTO messages (sender,receiver,msgbody) VALUES (1,2,'welcome'), (1,3,'welcome'), (1,4,'welcome'). but i want to pass the receiver values in an array. because, it will change dynamically in future.

Comment: There's no such thing as an array in MySQL. Are you talking about MySQL plus some other language?

Comment: i'm using mysql only.. all i want is insert multiple rows with same values for sender, messaage. but for receiver count may increase or decrease based on requirement

Comment: SQL isn't a very flexible or feature complete language, it's just a data insertion and query interface. You're responsible for composing these queries, and if you're doing that by hand for large lists, yes, it will be time consuming. That's why involving a scripting language, *any* scripting language, is a huge step up.